# Internal Error with AuthComponent Logout in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I am facing issue in implementing the Authentication in Cakephp(version = 2.5.3).
Login functionality works fine, but whenever I click logout, the following exceptions are generated in the error.log

```
0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/v1/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/Auth/BaseAuthorize.php(72): ControllerAuthorize->controller(Object(UsersController))
1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/v1/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php(500): BaseAuthorize->__construct(Object(ComponentCollection), Array)
2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/v1/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php(462): AuthComponent->constructAuthorize()
3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/v1/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php(309): AuthComponent->isAuthorized(Array)
4 [internal function]: AuthComponent->startup(Object(UsersController))
5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/v1/lib/Cake/Utility/ObjectCollection.php(128): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
6 [internal function]: ObjectCollection->trigger(Object(CakeEvent))
7 /opt/lampp/htdocs/v1/lib/Cake/Event/CakeEventManager.php(242): call_user_func(Array, Object(CakeEvent))
8 /opt/lampp/htdocs/v1/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php(675): CakeEventManager->dispatch(Object(CakeEvent))
9 /opt/lampp/htdocs/v1/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(187): Controller->startupProcess()
10 /opt/lampp/htdocs/v1/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(165): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(UsersController), Object(CakeRequest))
11 /opt/lampp/htdocs/v1/app/webroot/index.php(108): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
12 {main}
```

Following are the different files wherein the functionality of login and logout are coded

AppController.php

```
class AppController extends Controller {

public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array('authenticate' => array('Form' => array('passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish', 'userModel' => 'User','fields' => array('username' => 'user_name', 'password' => 'password'))),
                    'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'talks','action' => 'index'),
                    'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages','action' => 'display','home'),
                    'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login' ),
                    'authorize' => array('Controller')
    )
);

public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
}

}
```

UsersController.php

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class UsersController extends AppController {

//put your code here

public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('add', 'login');
}

public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}

public function logout() {
    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}

}
```

The following code is for the display of login and logout links

```
<?php if(!$this->Session->read('Auth.User')){ ?>
LOGIN FORM GENERATION CODE
            <?php }else{
            echo $this->Html->link(
                        'LOGOUT', array(
                                       'controller' => 'users',
                                       'action' => 'logout',
                                       'full_base' => true)
                                  );
         } ?>
```

I also do not have a lot of idea on how to debug Cakephp applications. So if somebody could at least point me in the right direction of debugging would also be very helpful.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After giving a little more thought and going through Caakephp API documentation, I found out that I was not overriding the isAuthorized() method in my UsersController.

I added the following to my Controller:

```
public function isAuthorized() {
    return true;
}
```

I return true always as I do not have any group. I just have one type of user.